# Excel txt file import when column headings and data values are always right-aligned

Tags: excel, vba, import, text-files

I have a large txt file, which consists on a matrix in which column headings and data values are always right-aligned. This is the only "regular feature" I can find to allow for importing the txt to excel, because elements are separated by an irregular number of spaces depending on the size of the data numbers.

The matrix has empty cells in several positions. It looks like this:

```
              4536        4705        2360        2355        2717       
 56099                                                      5156.5 
 12470      4114.9                                                                 
 12469                    23.0                                          
 56997                  2311.9                                             
 12471                                                                 
 12479                                                                 
 12473                                                                 
 12478        41.1                                                               
 12484                                         78957.7                      
 12477                                                                 
 12483                                                                 
 12476                           7125444.9
```

Any suggestion on how to do the import with VBA? How can I call for the condition of being aligned to the right? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in your post is right aligned to column width of 12.

This macro will open the txt file `data2` which contains the information in your post and appropriately set the columns.

```
Sub OpenMatrixData()
    Dim filename As String
    filename = "C:\Test\data2.txt"
    Dim firstColumnWidth As Integer
    Dim columnWidth As Integer

    firstColumnWidth = 6
    columnWidth = 12

    Workbooks.OpenText filename:=filename, Origin:=437, StartRow:= _
        1, _
        DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), _
        Array(firstColumnWidth, 1), _
        Array(firstColumnWidth + columnWidth * 1, 1), _
        Array(firstColumnWidth + columnWidth * 2, 1), _
        Array(firstColumnWidth + columnWidth * 3, 1), _
        Array(firstColumnWidth + columnWidth * 4, 1), _
        Array(firstColumnWidth + columnWidth * 5, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Excel Alignment:

```
|    |  4536|  4705|     2360|   2355|   2717|
56099|      |      |         |       | 5156.5|
12470|4114.9|      |         |       |       |
12469|      |    23|         |       |       |
56997|      |2311.9|         |       |       |
12471|      |      |         |       |       |
12479|      |      |         |       |       |
12473|      |      |         |       |       |
12478|  41.1|      |         |       |       |
12484|      |      |         |78957.7|       |
12477|      |      |         |       |       |
12483|      |      |         |       |       |
12476|      |      |7125444.9|       |       |
```

**In response to OP comments:**

For a dynamic number of columns you can give this a try, which relies on `Excel` to figure out how to treat the data.  It works with the example, but isn't as robust as the above solution.

```
Sub OpenMatrixData()
    Dim filename As String
    filename = "C:\Test\data2.txt"

    Workbooks.OpenText filename:=filename
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works with the example, but the original data has more than 500 columns. How to loop your macro for n columns?

Comment: @user12975 Well, it helps when you state the whole problem.  Even better when you post your attended code.  Restate your question to include the variable columns and I'll see what I can find out about a solution.  :)